# Remove item from ASP listbox in client side script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox, client-side

I am using this JavaScript code to delete the selected item in a listbox named lbResources when the user clicks a button:

```
var listResources = document.getElementById('lbResources');
listResources.options.remove(listResources.selectedIndex);
```

This removes the item from the listbox, but on postback to the server, the item still exists in the code behind. Is there any way to get the code behind list box object to reflect an item remove on the client side? Is this a time I should use a standard HTML listbox instead of an ASP .NET control?

I can simply use a hidden field to hold the data I need to pass for a postback, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET control keeps rendering in the same way each time you do a postback or page load. It doesn't care what you did on client side. It's interested only in values of the controls. It also validates itself against viewstate. You simply can not do that.

I'd recommend using hidden field to pass the items you want to remove and updatepanel to prevent the page to be fully loaded.

Or you can use standard HTML input but it depends on whether you need to know other than selected values on server side.